# Laravel api authenticates POST requests but returns 'Unauthenticated' with GET

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, routes

I have setup a Route group to authenticate my API calls with a token.

POST requests work fine, valid token passes authentication and an invalid one returns "Unauthenticated" as expected.

When making a GET request I get "Unauthenticated" every time.

I'm making GET requests with the same `api_token` that I made the POST requests with and still get "Unauthenticated"

**This is my route group**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'api']], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'ApiPostController@store');
    Route::get('/', 'ApiPostController@fetch');
});
```

I tried removing the POST route from the group, that didn't work. Tried changing the route (from `/` to `/get`) that didn't do anything either.

What is causing the GET requests to fail even though I'm sending a valid token?

Comment: How do you send `api_token`?  In headers, query or etc?

Comment: @V-K I'm sending it in the request body, I'm using postman

Comment: I think the problem can be in it because the request body is different for GET and POST

Comment: @V-K That was indeed the problem. I sent it in a header like this: `Authorization: Bearer api_token` and it worked. If you want type up an answer I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you send `api_token` in body and the request body is different for GET and POST requests. Also sending tokens in the GET body is insecure, that's why you have to send tokens via headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Apache server you can try adding those line in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

you can also clear config and try

```
php artisan config:clear
```

you can add @csrf as well.

Comment: I'm currently running the project locally with `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` . Clearing config didn't help either.